# Entity Framework - _objectTypeCount after disposing

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, dispose

In my website I've a ObjectContextStorage which keeps all the ObjectContext in them. After the http-request is done I throw away this storage (remove it from HttpContext.Current.Items)  and dispose the ObjectContexts in this storage.

Now when I debug and look at the _objectTypeCount of my ObjectContext it keeps raising when I reload my website while I would think the old ObjectContext is disposed??

Why is the old ObjectContext still in my memory after disposing it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are watching a **static** variable of the `ObjectContext` class:

```
private static int _objectTypeCount; // Bid counter
internal readonly int ObjectID = System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(
                                                       ref _objectTypeCount);
```

I've no clue what's the purpose of this. (It counts how often an ObjectContext has been created during an application or session lifetime, or something ???)

But because it's **static** you cannot conclude from an ever increasing counter that your `ObjectContext` **instances** haven't been removed from memory.

**Edit**

This counter and the `ObjectID` in the code apparently has to to with so called [BID tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc765421%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). "**BID**" stands for "**Built-In-Diagnostics**". The internal code construct above occurs in many ADO.NET classes. It is used just for tracing method calls in those classes and occurs in trace functions like this:

```
EntityBid.Trace("<ec.EntityCommandDefinition.CreateCommand|ADV> %d#\n",ObjectID);
```

The `_objectTypeCount` and the `ObjectID` are just there to give an instance of a type a name (or unique ID) for tracing output.

Aside from tracing it has no functional meaning inside of the `ObjectContext` class.

Comment: Thanks for the response and sorry for the late comment on this. Is there another way of looking how many instances of the ObjectContext are currently in the memory?

Comment: @Julian: Unfortunately I don't know. I believe that `ObjectContext` is not special in that matter. It probably comes down to the question: "How to check if an object is still in memory or already garbage collected?" or something... My knowledge of .NET system infrastructure isn't good enough to answer this question myself. Would be an interesting new question :)